# Can I include a single React component in a non-React environment via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'd like to achieve is the ability to dynamically add single react components to a vanilla (or any other project) via Javascript.

Essentially a web component, without the compatibility woes.

For example:
I create a component in React, build the project and it makes a bundle. Let's say I call the bundle "mycomponent.js"

Is there a way to then include that file in an unrelated project, either in an HTML script tag or bundler, then add it to the DOM dynamically with:

```
const elRef = new myCustomElement() //or some other syntax
elRef.customEvent = (data) => { console.log(data) }
document.body.appendChild(elRef)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you just need to set a mounting node for react to render your components. Something like:

```
<div>
  <!-- rest of your page -->
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!-- rest of your page -->
</div>

//Somewhere in your JS
React.render(<YourComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

React won't change anything outside of its mounting DOM node, so you can have a full page and render only some widget with react if you want to. You don't need to render the entire page with react